# remove search string/ query attribute from where condition for multiple attribute search. remove blank attribute for blank params from where condition

Tags: mysql, ruby-on-rails, ruby

I want to search products from Product table with multiple params but i want to only search for those params not blank. i am using this query for this.

```
@search_result = Product.where(:status_id=>1,:brand_id => @brand_id,   :product_name_id => @product_name_id, :size_id => @product_size_id,  :product_type_id => @product_type_id )
```

i want like this
if @product_name_id.blank? then the query should be like

```
@search_result = Product.where(:status_id=>1,:brand_id => @brand_id, :size_id => @product_size_id,  :product_type_id => @product_type_id )
```

@product_name_id should be removed from the query. i also tried

```
@search_result = Product.find_by_sql [
                                             "SELECT * FROM products WHERE status_id = ? AND brand_id > ? AND product_name_id > ? AND size_id > ? AND product_type_id > ? AND grade > ? ",
                                             "#{1}",
                                             "#{ unless @brand_id.blank?
                                                   @brand_id
                                                 end

                                              }",
                                             "#{ unless @product_name_id.blank?
                                                    @product_name_id
                                                 end

                                              }",
                                             "#{ unless @product_size_id.blank?
                                                    @product_size_id
                                                 end

                                              }",
                                             "#{ unless @product_type_id.blank?
                                                   @product_type_id
                                                 end

                                              }",
                                             "#{ unless @grade.blank?
                                                   @grade
                                                 end

                                              }"
                                         ]
```

But it's not give the my desired result i mean return wrong result.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The trick work for me now is using strong parameter

```
@search_result =Product.where(search_params)
```

and

```
def search_params
  my_where_params = params.permit(:product_type_id, :brand_id,:product_name_id,:grade,:size_id).select {|k,v| v.present?}
end
```

its removed the attribute for blank params.